# Clipping rounded corners on a NSScrollView

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, appkit

I have a simple custom borderless NSWindow subclass which has a rounded rectangle shape.

In the content view of this window, I've added an NSScrollView.

How do I get the NSScrollView to clip its document view to the rounded rectangle shape of the NSWindow?

I've tried subclassing the NSScrollView, overriding drawRect: and adding a clipping path before calling super.  I've also tried subclassing the document view and the clip view with the same technique but I cannot get it to clip.

BTW, this is on Lion with the elastic scrolling behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

After much fiddling, I just discovered that `NSScrollView`'s can be made to have rounded corners by simply giving it a backing layer and setting that layer's corner radius *provided* you also do the same to it's internal `NSClipView`. Both are required, which now makes sense, since it's the clip view that actually provides the viewable window into the `NSScrollView`'s document view.

```
NSScrollView * scrollView = ...;

// Give the NSScrollView a backing layer and set it's corner radius.
[scrollView setWantsLayer:YES];
[scrollView.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];

// Give the NSScrollView's internal clip view a backing layer and set it's corner radius.
[scrollView.contentView setWantsLayer:YES];
[scrollView.contentView.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];
```

Comment: Note however, that this doesn't seem to work for NSScrollView's that contain NSTextView's. In this case, we need to revert back to the masking layer approach.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268467/how-can-i-get-nsscrollview-to-respect-a-clipping-path/9989911#9989911

Answer (score 0):

Even better IMO:

```
scrollView.wantsLayer = true
scrollView.layer?.masksToBounds = true
scrollView.contentView.wantsLayer = true
scrollView.contentView.layer?.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this. Unfortunatelly this solution doesn't work for me...

Comment: Eh. Yes? Have you actually considered that this answer is over 2 years old and that it might have worked "back then"? :)

Comment: Please don't get me wrong :) Sorry, I have decided to check, as there was no comments to this answer. Thank you for finding time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift I have solved like this:

```
scrollView.wantsLayer = true
scrollView.contentView.wantsLayer = true
scrollView.layer?.cornerRadius = 20.0
scrollView.contentView.layer?.cornerRadius = 20.0
```